# Cypress - when identity redirect on other url my tests can't continue

Tags: cypress

I'm testing my project remotely without mocking test data. But I have a problem that in step login project, redirect on the other url and my tests failed

Can you introduce a other tool or method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your issue, I see that when you say `cy.visit('url')` and after this is executed your website domain most likely changed to different one. Cypress does not support multiple domains.

If you can show your code snippet, I can help you solve the issue.